# I want send mail After registration but it throws following exception?

Tags: spring-security

```
    SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
    message.setFrom("xxxxxx@gmail.com");
    message.setTo("abc@gmail.coom");
    message.setSubject("Hello Test Mail");
    message.setText("Hello How r u?");

        JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        /*mailSender.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");*/
        mailSender.setPort(287);
        //Set gmail email id
        mailSender.setUsername("xyz@gmail.com");
        //Set gmail email password
        mailSender.setPassword("123");

        Properties prop = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();
        prop.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        prop.put("mail.debug", "true");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

     try{
         mailSender.send(message);
     }
     catch (MailException ex) {
         // simply log it and go on...
         System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
     }
```

but gives me following exception

Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 287;

nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect. 
    Failed messages:
    javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP 
    host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 287;

```
nested exception is:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

Answer (score 0):

Port `587` is the port for using Google Gmails SMTP server (With TLS).

You are setting the port to `287` in your `mailSender` object.

Remove that setter and it should use the configured `prop.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");` to send your mail.